# JTAPI Getting all the events of all calls

Tags: java, jtapi

Colleagues, could you be so kind to help me with the following problem: what `Observer` will give me the ability to track all events (for `Cisco UCM`)? I've seen somewhere that it is possible, and even there it is possible to set what to filter. The goal is to catch the event `FORWADRNOANSWER`, then track how the connection is closed on the second leg. I don't want to put `CallObserver` on all terminals or address, and I am not sure if it is possible... 
Also the second leg which is created due to `FORWADRNOANSWER` terminal or address is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, i can help you with the code, but for cucm setup cant help you very much...

first you need to install cucm client on server, you can download from cucm server.

Comment: JTAPI lib installed. What do you mean by "cucm client"?

Comment: sorry, i means Cisco JTAPI Client, its in cucm->Application->plugin->search bar[JTAPI]

Comment: contact me at zafirovantonie@hotmail.com if you need further help